# 404 error when trying to Automate CloudFlare log push job with terraform

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

Hope this is the correct place.
Essentially, I want to automate applying some base settings and setting up the log push.
The date/resources I am using:

```
data "cloudflare_zone" "zone" {
  name       =  "example.com"
  account_id = "12334567
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "policy_document" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
  sid = "cloudflareput
  actions = [
    "s3:PutObject"
  ]
  principals {
    type        = "AWS"
  identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::123456:user/cloudflare-logpush-user"]
  }
  effect    = "Allow"
  resources = ["arn:aws:s3:::-cloudflare-logs/*"]
  }
}

data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "challenge" {
  bucket = "cloudflare-logs"
  key    = cloudflare_logpush_ownership_challenge.challenge.ownership_challenge_filename
}

module "s3-bucket" {
  source                  = "terraform-aws-modules/s3-bucket/aws"
  version                 = "2.9.0
  bucket                  = "cloudflare-logs"
}

resource "cloudflare_logpush_ownership_challenge" "challenge" {
  zone_id          = "12345678
  destination_conf = "s3://cloudflare-logs?region=us-east-1"
}

resource "cloudflare_logpush_job" "logpush_job" {
  enabled             = true
  zone_id             = data.cloudflare_zone.zone.id
  name                = "cloudflare-logpush-job"
  logpull_options     = "fields=RayID,ClientIP,ClientRequest,WAF,Origin,OriginResponse,Firewall,EdgeStartTimestamp&timestamps=rfc3339"
  destination_conf    = "s3://cloudflare-logs?region=us-east-1"
  ownership_challenge = data.aws_s3_bucket_object.challenge.body
  dataset             = "http_requests"
}
```

For some reason when I do this it 404's, saying the file doesn't exist. Now I have one from before. And if I manually put the file in the bucket it works... after the bucket creation. But, if I just do this from scratch it errors saying the challange file doesn't exist.

- -create bucket
- create challange file
- target newly created challange file
- setup log push job

Error: failed getting S3 Bucket (cloudflare-logs) Object (ownership-challenge-r64hsw26g.txt): NotFound: Not Found status code: 404, request id: 13414

...

in data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "s3_challenge_file": data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "s3_challenge_file" {

I get what it is saying. Essentially file not found.

Comment: S3 bucket names are globally unique **all AWS accounts ever created**. It could be that you are trying to access a bucket with the same name but which does not have the file you want. If the bucket name is not the reason it could also be that the object ACLs are not preserved. One way to fix this would be to somehow add `bucket-owner-full-control` to the object, but I'm pretty sure it can't be done with the data source, but rather with `aws_s3_bucket_object` resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object#acl.

Comment: So it isn't that it doesnt have a unique bucket. I think it is storing the file name of the  s3 file in state.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same issue and for me the ownership challenge file expired and was deleted by expiration rules set on the S3 bucket.  Hence, terraform complained that it could not find the challenge file on the bucket.  Once I recreated the ownership challenge file with the challenge as it's content, I was able to run and apply the terraform plan.  Check if there are any expiration rules for objects placed in the S3 bucket.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31251726)